# Modifying button size according to user's resolution

Tags: html, css, button

How can I make a button maintain it's size on different screen resolutions? I tried using '%' but it has only worked with divs so far.

```
.button{
        width:x;
        height:y;
       }
```

What values should x and y have so the button modifies according to screen resolution?

Comment: When you say you want it to be different sizes per resolution, what exactly do you mean? Like, if the resolution is `800x600` vs `1920x1080` but has the same pixel density, or are you talking about scaling up buttons on HDPI screens? If its the first one, you can use `@media` queries.

Comment: Percentage should work for a button.
Have you already set the width and height of all the parent elements including html and body to 100%?

Comment: Man you are so unclear. At first you say that you want to maintain the button size on different screen resolutions and at the and you ask to make button modifies according to screen resolution. What do you finally want to do ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding the view port sizes vw or vh will set the buttons to there browser size.
So if the browser is fullscreen it will be aproximatly to there resolution

```css
button {
  width: 10vw;
  height: 10vh;
}
body {
  height: 100vh;
}
```

```html
<button>Create</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using Padding like so and place it inline

```
.button
{

display:inline-block;
padding: 2%;

}
```

If you want to increase the height, play with line-height attributes like so

```
.button
{

line-height: 1.5rem;
display:inline-block;
padding: 2%;

}
```